# android internal memory usage

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android and I want to find free memory in internal storage. I use two function to find free memory but they show me two different values in long format. I don't know why?
Here is my code:

1) Result of getTIM() function is 558628864

```
public String getTIM(){
    File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    String str = Long.toString(blockSize * totalBlocks);
    return str;
}
```

2) Result of ITMStr() function is 914120704

```
public String ITMStr(){
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    long blockCount = statFs.getBlockCountLong();
    long blockSize = statFs.getBlockSizeLong();
    long total = blockCount * blockSize;
    String str = Long.toString(total);
    return str;
}
```

Which value is right?

Answer (score 0):

According to [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html):

> public static File getDataDirectory ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Return the user data directory.

_

> public static File getRootDirectory ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Return root of the "system" partition holding the
>   core Android OS. Always present and mounted read-only.

So sizes are different as you are getting sizes for different stuff.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to get total internal memory. For example total internal memory is 512MB and I want to show 512MB as total memory of the device. How can I make it?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but `getRootDirectory` should return the root partition, so it should be the total ammount of memory.